# Automake does not find pkg-config macros

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine

So I have found that update to a Wine issue regrading Qt5.  The fix calls for me to compile and install Mesa 10.4.1.  I got the source from  git.  So first I downloaded/installed the proper dependences such as `flex` `bison` `autoconfig` `aclocal` `pkg-config` and `Util-Dev` from repos.  `libdrm-2.4.58` `pixman-0.32.6` `dri3proto-1.0` and `automake-1.14` were source built using `./configure` and make/sudo make install.  After I came across this in the Terminal after typing in `./autogen.sh`

```
configure.ac:152: error: Could not locate the pkg-config autoconf macros.
  These are usually located in /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4. If your macros
  are in a different location, try setting the environment variable
ACLOCAL="aclocal -I/other/macro/dir" before running autoreconf.
configure.ac:152: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
```

[image: Proof in GUI]

and when I run `apt-file search pkg.m4`  The Terminal results in

When I did download and `./configure` and `make/install` those libraries, I left them in /Home.
    pkg-config: /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
    mm-common: /usr/share/aclocal/mm-pkg.m4

Comment: Did you install the `pkg-config` package on your system - if so how? Can you clarify which of the dependencies you have installed from the repositories, and which you are trying to build from source? What exactly do you mean by "left them in/Home" - did you configure them with `--prefix=$HOME`?

Comment: Pkg-config was installed via apt - get in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue.  What worked for me was installing `autoconf` and `pkgconf`.  I was then able to find `/usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4`.

Comment: Indeed, same here, I was missing `pkgconf`. Installed it and problem solved. Important to remove `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` first and to run `yarn install` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using system `autoconf`, you must export

```
AL_OPTS=-I/path/where/you/installed/the/stuff/share/aclocal
```

in your environment.

If you built and installed `autoconf` from source, you must export

```
AL_OPTS=-I/usr/share/aclocal
```

instead.

The point is that the `/path/where/you/installed/the/stuff/share/aclocal` or `/usr/share/aclocal` path you are putting into that `AL_OPTS` environment variable must be the one that contains the file `pkg.m4`.

If that does not work, try exporting `ACLOCAL` set to

`aclocal [what you wanted to put into AL_OPTS]`

instead, where the argument to aclocal in that variable is what you tried to put into `AL_OPTS`.